# Server room door automatic opener

Tags: server-room, physical-security

I'm looking to solve the problem of having the server room door open "automatically" when we need to move a large amount of equipment into the room.  The typical case is the lab admin gets a large box and holds it with both hands as he hip-checks the badge scanner and then kicks the door open.  It would be nice to have something like the ADA automatic door opener but with badge access.
Does anyone have experience with such a system or possible have a better idea of enabling "hands free" access while retaining security?  (Yes, we tried to make the obvious process fix of using a cart to keep your back safe and hands free, but the success rate is low)

edit: Sorry, but I don't think I described the issue correctly.  The problem isn't holding the door open (doorstop) but people opening the door with their hands full and kicking the door to do so.  The obvious solution is to not open the door with your hands full.  Telling people to do this (the process change) isn't effective.  If there is an $x,000 solution folks are familiar with, I'd appreciate sharing a solution.

Comment: I've seen plenty of server rooms and other secure locations with an ADA opener **as well as** a proximity badge reader. The ADA openers are designed such that if someone tries to activate the motor, it'll try to open the door, but will notice the resistance and will quit. Users just need to scan their badge and then hit the opener button.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's overlooking the common sense solution: a doorstop.

Comment: Does your office have an intern? Holding a door open is great on-the-job experience.

Comment: @ewwhite Doorstop kind of violates the whole principle of being able to open the door while carrying something heavy and then having the door close automatically. A doorstop is a fine idea for an unsecured environment but a *terrible* one for someplace that needs to be locked down.

Comment: @scottpack I work in a number of secured data center environments. None have automatic doors. They *do* have doorstops and rolling equipment carts and racks...

Comment: @ewwhite I find that pretty terrible for all kinds of reasons.

Answer (score 4):

How about a $2.99 door stop?  Seriously.  Putting an automatic door opening systems seems a bit much; never mind it'll be $$$.

Comment: +1 - Thank you! Common sense and simple solutions to (not very) complex problems win the day!

Comment: I like simple solutions as well, but I have seen inspectors get grumpy when they see door stops around rooms that have FM-200 (or the like) gas fire suppression systems.

Answer (score 1):

Can you get the badge system to, in addition to the normal door strike release, close a normally-open relay wired in-line with the button for the door opener, allowing the user to press the button for the opener when required (but still having it be optional), and not wear out the motor in the opener by opening against the locked strike?